# Locking a resource for update process (ReadWrite lock) In Container Enviroment

Tags: docker, synchronization, mutex, readwritelock

I have a python application that accesses a database (PostgreSQL) with a master data in order to search within it - done by a search **threads** (A 150 mb database).

Once a day there is an update process that updates the database (drops and loads a new table) - during the update the search threads are blocked until the update is completed.

Today it is implemented using a Read-Write lock on the application level.
Now we are moving into a search **processes** that each one of them runs in a docker container

What is the best way to achieve this functionality in the new environment? (Using distributed locks? explicit locking on the database level?...)

I saw the [Redis implementation for distributed locks](https://redis.io/topics/distlock), seems that they are exclusive and not RW.

Comment: Can you use database transactions to avoid the need for a lock – do the entire "update" sequence in a single transaction, so that individual queries either see the "before" or "after" state?

Comment: I think its a good option that definitely will check this out (pg_dump/pg_restore). I'm not sure if i can do table drops when other services are connected to the db - so it might be a limitation